# How to make url /username in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, uri, friendly-url

I'm using codeigniter at the moment. I am currently able to view a persons profile by the using `/user/profile/profile_id` but I want to make it so that a user can just navigate to a profile using `/username` to make it simpler.

How would I go about doing this I'm not sure where to start?

```
class User extends CI_Controller{  

public function index(){

    if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
        redirect('user/profile');
    }

}

public function profile(){

    $profile_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $ip = $this->session->userdata('ip_address');
    $curr_user = $this->session->userdata('id');

    $data['profile'] = $this->db->get_where('users', array('id' => $profile_id))->row_array();  
    $data['followers'] = $this->db->get_where('followers', array('following_id' => $profile_id))->num_rows();       
    $data['following'] = $this->db->get_where('followers', array('follower_id' => $profile_id))->num_rows();
    $data['doesFollow'] = $this->db->get_where('followers', array('follower_id' => $curr_user, 'following_id' => $profile_id))->num_rows();
    $data['posts'] = $this->db->get_where('posts', array('user_id' => $profile_id))->result_array();        

    $data['main_content'] = 'profile';  
    $this->load->view('template', $data);   

    $this->get_profile_view($profile_id, $ip, $curr_user);  

}

}
```

routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "signin";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

Comment: Please add more information

Comment: Could you add more information about asking me to add more information? What do you need to know?

Comment: navigate to a profile using user/username or user/profile/username?

Comment: That is the whole point why I want to make it just `www.mysite.com/username` instead of large url's like `user/profile/username`. I've had a look at CI documentation and it looks like a routing issue but I'm unsure how to use it. Do you know how I would route it so that it is `/username`

Comment: I would suggest posting your routes.php. You will need to create a catch all route to redirect all uris to the user controller.

Comment: @Jeemusu I've edited it to show the routes but it's just the standard routes file that comes with codeigniter as I mentioned I'm unsure about how to use routes. If you can help that would be fantastic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I take it that the functionality you're trying to achieve is the following:

1. If the user navigates to http://example.com/(route) and route is mapped by a controller, then display that controller.
2. If the user navigates to http://example.com/(route) and route is not mapped by any controller, then there is a chance the route is a username, and thus:

   1. If the route is a username, display that person's route.
   2. If the route is not a username, display a 404 page.

So the plan here is to create a custom 404 handler that checks if the provided route is a username, or else, it displays a 404 page.

The first thing we need to do is to set our custom 404 controller:

```
$route['404_override'] = 'profile';
```

We then create our custom 404 controller:

```
class Profile extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct(); 
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $username = $this->uri_segment(1);

        if (empty($username)) {
            $this->displayPageNotFound();
        }

        $this->load->model('muser');

        // Check if parameter is not a valid username.
        if (!$this->muser->checkIfUsername($username)) {
            $this->displayPageNotFound();
        } else {
            // Load data for user profile.
            $ip = $this->session->userdata('ip_address');
            $curr_user = $this->session->userdata('id');

            $data['profile'] = $this->db->get_where('users', array('id' => $profile_id))->row_array();  
            $data['followers'] = $this->db->get_where('followers', array('following_id' => $profile_id))->num_rows();       
            $data['following'] = $this->db->get_where('followers', array('follower_id' => $profile_id))->num_rows();
            $data['doesFollow'] = $this->db->get_where('followers', array('follower_id' => $curr_user, 'following_id' => $profile_id))->num_rows();
            $data['posts'] = $this->db->get_where('posts', array('user_id' => $profile_id))->result_array();        

            $data['main_content'] = 'profile';  
            $this->load->view('template', $data);   

            $this->get_profile_view($profile_id, $ip, $curr_user);  
        }
    }

    protected function displayPageNotFound() {
        $this->output->set_status_header('404');
        $this->load->view('page_not_found');
    }
}
```

The only thing left to implement is the muser model with the checkIfUsername() method. Let me know if you need more information on this.

Comment: +1 and can use **`show_404()`** instead of a custom method **`displayPageNotFound`**