# Custom Profile URL Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to create the custom profile url like site/u/username
i found this one [How to make url /username in codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19336567/how-to-make-url-username-in-codeigniter)

but until now it still show 404. when i'm trying to access site/u/username

**my routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] = "guest";
$route['404_override'] = 'u';
```

**my model**

```
   function cekuser($username)
   {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE username = '$username'");
        $query = $query->result_array();
        if($query){
            return $query[0];
        };
   }
```

**my controller**

```
<?php class U extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct(); 
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $username = $this->uri->segment(1);

        if (empty($username)) {
            $this->show_404();
        }

        $this->load->model('m_login');

        // Check if parameter is not a valid username.
        if (!$this->m_login->cekuser($username)) {
            $this->displayPageNotFound();
        } else { 
            $this->load->view('template');
        }
    }

    protected function displayPageNotFound() {
        $this->output->set_status_header('404');
        $this->load->view('notfound');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## route.php

instead of `$route['404_override'] = 'u';`

Add

```
$route['u/(:any)'] = 'u/showuserinfo';
```

## In Controller

**Add** a method

```
function showuserinfo($name)
{
 $this->load->model('m_login');
  if (empty($name))
  {
        $name = $this->uri->segment(2);
  }
  $user = $this->m_login->cekuser($name);
  if (!empty($user))
  {
        $this->load->view('template', $user);
  }
  else
  {
        echo 'User Not found';
  }
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function cekuser() on a non-object. Undefined property: U::$m_login. Missing argument 1 for U::showuserinfo()

Comment: sorry, i'm forget to load my model. this solve my problem, thanks!

Comment: Did you mean `$route['u/(:any)'] = 'u/showuserinfo/$1';`?

Answer (score 1):

```
$route['404_override'] = 'controller name';
```

Add

```
$route['controller name/(:any)'] = 'controller name/any name';
```